# Do i still need IP restriction on my server if I am using key based auth?

Tags: ssh, server

I currently have ip restrictions set such that I can only SSH into my server from either the office or my home. I expect to travel around to various sites over the next few months and thus need to change this.

Is it relatively secure just to have key based auth (and turn password auth off) and expose the ssh port to anyone? Or should I look into dyndns or noip for my laptop and only allowing SSH from that account?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

TBH, the IP restriction is crap in my opinion. Never used it in over 10 years I've been using Linux.

Just disable password authentication, root login and change the port. With these three things, you're 99.999999% safe from a SSH point of view, unless:

- OpenSSH has a vulnerability.
- You expose your private key.

Basically, just changing the port you will not receive any attack unless it's from someone that specifically wants to attack you.